# Compare columns between different files

Tags: command-line, text-processing, files, awk

I have multiple files ( about 20 files with 30000 lines and 32 columns) and I need to keep only the lines that start with the same string.
I found these cases that are quite similar to what I need but I don't know how to adapt them..

[compare multiple files(more than two) with two different columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214139/compare-multiple-filesmore-than-two-with-two-different-columns)

[how to compare values in two columns in two different files, echoing full lines where absolute value of difference is < a small maximum value?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171737/how-to-compare-values-in-two-columns-in-two-different-files-echoing-full-lines)

In my case each file has a first column made of strings of 12 characters, I need to keep only the lines starting with strings that are present in ALL the files. (one file for every input file or also a single output file like the one in the above mentioned cases is fine).
My files are like this:

**file1**:

```
 -13  -5   0 19.3769 46.9197   1
 -13  -4  -2 347.911 57.7232   1
 -13  -4  -1 38.5696 39.0027   1
 -13  -4   0 2227.39 124.894   1
 -13  -3  -3 113.001 40.2117   1
 -13  -3  -2 850.847 78.2881   1
```

**file2**:

```
 -13  -5   0 2.19085 50.4632   1
 -13  -4  -2 283.628 56.7731   1
 -13  -4  -1  41.179 48.6423   1
 -13  -4   0 1753.54  125.88   1
 -13  -3  -3 28.2363 40.6518   1
 -13  -3  -2 562.736 66.0301   1
 -13  -3  -1 750.747 77.2795   1
```

Output **file1**:

```
 -13  -5   0 19.3769 46.9197   1
 -13  -4  -2 347.911 57.7232   1
 -13  -4  -1 38.5696 39.0027   1
 -13  -3  -3 113.001 40.2117   1
 -13  -3  -2 850.847 78.2881   1
```

Output **file2**

```
 -13  -5   0 2.19085 50.4632   1
 -13  -4  -2 283.628 56.7731   1
 -13  -4  -1  41.179 48.6423   1
 -13  -3  -3 28.2363 40.6518   1
 -13  -3  -2 562.736 66.0301   1
```

Comment: Shouldn't your output for `file1` also contain `-13  -4  -1 38.5696 39.0027   1`? The string ` -13  -4  -1` is in both `file1` and `file2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to first find all sets of 12 initial characters that are present in more than one file:

```
cut -c-12 file* | sort | uniq -c
```

The `cut` command above prints the 1st 12 characters from every file whose name starts with `file`, these are then sorted and the number of times each line is found is appended by `uniq -c`. Running this on your example files returns:

```
$ cut -c-12 file* | sort | uniq -c
      1  -13  -3  -1
      2  -13  -3  -2
      2  -13  -3  -3
      2  -13  -4   0
      2  -13  -4  -1
      2  -13  -4  -2
      2  -13  -5   0
```

So, all lines but the 1st appear in both files. Now, keep only those lines that appear the desired number of times (20 in your case):

```
cut -c-12 file* | sort | uniq -c | rev | sed -n 's/ 20 *$//p' | rev
```

`rev` simply prints its input reversed. I am using it here to make the number of times each line was seen the last field. This is then passed to `sed` which is told to only print lines which end with a space, a 20 and 0 or more spaces. This keeps only lines that appeared 20 times and the final `rev` brings us back to the original format.

You can now pass the whole thing to `grep` as a list of strings to search for:

```
$ grep -f <(cut -c-12 file* | sort | uniq -c | 
            rev | sed -n 's/ 20 *$//p' | rev) file*
 -13  -5   0 19.3769 46.9197   1
 -13  -4  -2 347.911 57.7232   1
 -13  -4  -1 38.5696 39.0027   1
 -13  -4   0 2227.39 124.894   1
 -13  -3  -3 113.001 40.2117   1
 -13  -3  -2 850.847 78.2881   1
```

If your shell doesn't support the `<()` format, you could save the results of `cut` in a separate file and use that, or just run it in a loop:

```
cut -c-12 file* | sort | uniq -d | 
    while IFS= read -r l; do grep -- "^$l" file1; done
```

To have each file's output in a separate file, use:

```
cut -c-12 file* | sort | uniq -c | rev | sed -n 's/ 20 *$//p' | rev > list
for f in file*; do grep -f list "$f" > "$f.new"; done
```

Comment: Thanks for answering,
the problem is that I need to keep only the strings that are present in all the files, let's say if it is present in 9 files over 10 it has to be discarded.

Comment: @Eleonora sorry about that, try the updated answer.

Comment: `rev`'s definitely not needed here: `sed '/^[[:blank:]]\{1,\}20 /!d;//s///'`

Comment: @don_crissti I find the two revs clearer and simpler.

Comment: @Terdon thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. It works perfectly.